# Cumsum by group and deal with NAs

Tags: r, datatable, na, cumsum

I have data in long format which looks like:

```
ID<-c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D")
CW<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Value<-c(1,1,3,3,NA,NA,6,6)
dt<-cbind(ID,CW,Value)
```

I want to calculate `cumsum()` for `dt$Value`, the result should look like:

```
cum<-c(1,1,4,4,NA,NA,10,10)
dt.cum<-cbind(dt,cum)
```

I formatted `dt` as datatable and tried something like:

```
dt[, cum := cumsum(ifelse(is.na(dt$Value), 0, dt$Value)) +dt$Value*0, by="CW"]
```

However, this did not work.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely how you functionally define your `cum` column? Do you take nto account only values when `CW`=1? I mean: "real" cumsum would be `c(1,2,4,7,(eventually NA), (eventually NA), 13, 19) ` You want a (distinct) `cumsum` per `CW` values having NA counting for 0?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `cbind` to create a data frame. `cbind` returns a `matrix`, and, in this case, all its elements are coerced to class `character`.

```
dt <- data.frame(ID,CW,Value)
```

Now, here is a base `R` solution. Function `ave`is meant for this kind of problem.

```
dt$cum <- ave(dt$Value, dt$CW, FUN = function(x) cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))
is.na(dt$cum) <- is.na(dt$Value)
dt$cum
[1]  1  1  4  4 NA NA 10 10
```